# AWS Inspector Agent Unhealthy: Account not registered in this AWS region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Trying out AWS Inspector on Amazon Linux 2.
[Installing manually](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/inspector/latest/userguide/inspector_installing-uninstalling-agents.html#install-linux)
[Added proxy details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/inspector/latest/userguide/inspector_agents-on-linux.html#inspector-agent-proxy-linux) because we are behind a proxy server

Install was successful but the following error is in the logs (sudo systemctl status awsagent.service):

```
Publishers/ArsenalPublisher.cpp:1070:RegisterEC2Agent operation not permitted failure : Account not registered in this AWS region. AccountID : <redacted>
Publishers/ArsenalPublisher.cpp:649:Agent failed to register during config retrieval: Operation not permitted: Account not registered in this AWS region. AccountID : <redacted>
Service/MainInspectorThread.cpp:80:Config retrieval failed : -96
```

This matches the status at:

```
sudo /opt/aws/awsagent/bin/awsagent status | less

Last registration attempt date : Thu 2018-10-11 23:15:01 UTC
Registration failure reason : Operation not permitted: Account not registered in this AWS region. AccountID : <redacted>
Config retrieval failure reason : Agent failed to register during config retrieval
```

And the region in the above file was confirmed to match the region.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that AWS Inspector needs a bit of time to register.

While writing up the question, searching the internet generally, and viewing the FAQs for the service, the agent resolved itself.

```
sudo /opt/aws/awsagent/bin/awsagent status | less
```

Now shows:

```
Last registration attempt date : Thu 2018-10-11 23:35:44 UTC
Last registration date : Thu 2018-10-11 23:35:45 UTC
Last config retrieval attempt date : Thu 2018-10-11 23:40:21 UTC
Last config retrieval date : Thu 2018-10-11 23:40:21 UTC
```